# Aggregate N-times (by partition) in one query? CTE?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Net hires for a date range

I have a set of employee data with these fields. termination date is null if they're still active.

```
id   |    hire date    | termination date
1           7/25/11     |         null
2           12/01/10    |  7/30/11
3           7/20        |  null
4           7/16        | 7/29/11
```

What I need to get is for a rolling 13 week period is:

```
week ending date     Net hires
07-17                   1
07-24                   1
07-31          -1
```

...

I've begun doing it with a CTE and then using unions because I gave up trying to figure it out the better way. I have to do this for some other fields too so maybe there's a better way, maybe using pivot/unpivot?

Rough pseudocode of what I have now.

```
;with foo
as
(
select *
from employee
--joins and conditions
)
select @report_date, sum(case when hire date > report_date-7 and hire_date < report_date then 1 else 0 end)(

... etc
```

I'll take care of dates with no hires/terminations later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that you are putting all of these `UNION`s together with a hard-coded column should tell you that you're missing a set somewhere. In this case it's the set of weeks. Put those in a table (permanent, temporary, or virtual via a CTE) and this query becomes trivial.

```
SELECT
    WKS.start_date,
    COUNT(E.employee_id)
FROM
    Report_Weeks WKS
LEFT OUTER JOIN Employees E ON
    E.hire_date > WKS.start_date AND
    E.hire_date < WKS.end_date
GROUP BY
    WKS.start_date
ORDER BY
    WKS.start_date
```

Since you refer to "net" hires I'm guessing that you want to work in the terminations as well. You can do that by turning it into a `SUM(CASE...)` where you use 1 for new hires, 0 for people outside of that week or who were hired then fired within the same week, and -1 for terminations.

As JNK points out, order matters in the `CASE` statement. Also, you can use the `ELSE` to handle the 0 values. I would suggest something like this:

```
CASE
    WHEN
        E.hire_date BETWEEN WKS.start_date AND WKS.end_date AND
        E.termination_date > WKS.end_date THEN 1
    WHEN
        E.termination_date BETWEEN WKS.start_date AND WKS.end_date AND
        E.hire_date < WKS.end_date THEN -1
    ELSE 0
END
```

Since I used `BETWEEN` there you need to make sure that your start date for one week isn't exactly the same as the end date for the previous week.

Comment: Bear in mind if you use the 3 part `CASE` logic described **ORDER MATTERS IN CASE** - i.e. if you check for Hires, then fires, then hires and fires you will never have results for the third set because they will all be caught into one of the first two.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. The case statement was what I was missing in my first attempt. Makes it seem so simple. Note: I had to make a small change in the first 'case when'. I added 'or termination_date is null in parenthesis. It was excluding all those hires with no termination date.